# batch adding users days

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am currently working on a project for a class I am taking that has to deal with batch files and adding users. I can do the entire problem by my self, With the exception of a single piece. In order to get full credit for the project, I have to create new users and set the days they can access to mon through fri, 8am to 5pm. What I am having trouble with is how to input the days and times to the net user command.

so far as I am aware, I need to do something similar to this

> > >net user /add %NAME% %PASS% /times{800,1700|mon-fri}

but the syntax is incorrect, giving me an invalid day range error.

Thanks

Comment: Try `/times:monday-friday,8am-5pm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these sites: http://ss64.com/nt/netuseroptions.html and https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_user.mspx?mfr=true

> /times:{times | all} The times the user is allowed to use the
>   computer. The times value is expressed as day[-day][,day[-day]] ,
>   time[-time][,time[-time]], limited to 1-hour time increments. Days can
>   be spelled out or abbreviated (M,T,W,Th,F,Sa,Su). Hours can be 12- or
>   24-hour notation. For 12-hour notation, use AM, PM, or A.M., P.M. The
>   value all means a user can always log on. A null value (blank) means a
>   user can never log on. Separate day and time with commas, and units of
>   day and time with semicolons (for example, M,4AM-5PM;T,1PM-3PM). Do
>   not use spaces when designating /times.

So the command line should look something like this:

```
net user %NAME% %PASS% /ADD
net user %NAME% /time:M-F,08:00-17:00
```

You can also use the am/pm format:

```
net user %NAME% %PASS% /ADD
net user %NAME% /time:M-F,8am-5pm
```